Display a list of objects from SwiftData with a Toggle and no bool in the object
I would like to display a list of objects queried from SwiftData, each objects having a Toggle. I obviously need a bool for each object for the state of the toggle. The usual way of doing things is to put a isChecked member in the Student object, but I can't (the actual code is worse as I don't have only two courses, maths and physics, but a list of courses coming from a query from the database). Of course, a student can appear in many different courses, so I can't even have one isChecked in the Student object that could work for all the courses.
@Model
final class Student {
  var name: String = ""
  ...
}

import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct ClassView: View {
  @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
  var group: Group

  var body: some View {
    List {
      Section("Maths") {
        ForEach(mathStudents(group: group)) { student in
          HStack{
            Text(student.name)
            Toggle(isOn: ???) {}.onChange(of: ???) { oldValue, newValue in
              ...some code...
            }
          }
        }
      }
      Section("Physics") {
        ForEach(physicsStudents(group: group)) { student in
          HStack{
            Text(student.name)
            Toggle(isOn: ???) {}.onChange(of: ???) { oldValue, newValue in
              ...some code...
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  var mathStudents(group: Group) -> [Student] {
    ...        
  }

  var physicsStudents(group: Group) -> [Student] {
    ...        
  }
}

So my question, is : Where can I put my family of bool for the toggles and how can I initialize them ?

What is the toggle mean to represent, what changes when you toggle it?

Note, Class is already used in Swift as a keyword to describe a Swift Class, I suggest you use something else for your code.

@JoakimDanielson : When I toggle it, it creates a new SwiftData object.

Could you be a little clearer, which type of object is created and how is it related to Student and Class?

You can use a computed binding for that, e.g.
let student: Student
let group: Group

var isInGroupBinding: Binding<Bool> {
    Binding<Bool>(get: {
       // return true if student is in the group.
    }, set: { newValue in
        // if newValue is true then add student to the group,
        // if false remove from the group.
    })
}

Then you can use it like this:
Toggle(isOn: isInGroupBinding)

